# can't dup NilClass - Rails

Tags: rspec, model

When I run RSpec I get the error `can't dup NilClass`.

I have tried adding `unloadable` but it doesn't fix it.

I presume this is the function that is causing the error:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_save :create_permalink

  validates :username,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50, minimum: 3 }, 
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :permalink, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50, minimum: 3 }, 
                        uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  private

    def create_permalink
      self.permalink = username.dup.parameterize
    end
end
```

user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: Faker::Name.name, username: "example",
                     email: Faker::Internet.email, password: "password",
                     password_confirmation: "password")
  end

  .
  .
  .

end
```

Failing tests include:

```
it { should validate_presence_of(:username) }
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:permalink) }
```

I have also tried adding:

```
config.reload_plugins = true if RAILS_ENV == ‘development’
```

to my environment.rb file, but again that did not work.

How would I stop this happening as it is making my tests fail?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Apologies, I though it was obvious. The question is now at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You have a test that is creating a `User` object with a nil `username`. There are several possible fixes for this, its hard to pick one without seeing the test code itself. It could be as simple as specifying the username when you set up your test user, e.g.

```
user = User.create username: 'Test User'
```

Include your RSpec test code in the question if its more complicated than that.

As it stands username is a required field in your User model so its probably worth adding a validation for it:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true
  ...
end
```

Validations run before the `before_save` filter so you will get a more meaningful error in your tests.

Comment: I have updated the question with my User validations that were already present when I ran the tests and the RSpec I am running.

Comment: Could you also include the failing code example (`it` block)? The `@user` you are setting up in the `before` block is fine (it sets the `username` field), so maybe there is a different `User` object coming into play in the failing test.

Comment: I believe I have found the issue, I was using the shoulda gem for testing and it seems there is a compatibility issue.